# How to scroll a larger div in an overflow:hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="start">
    <div id="largediv">
        <div id="ball"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div start has for example fixed height and width like `500px x 500px` 
and the div `largediv` has `1000px x 1000px`. I can move the ball in the 500x500px area but I don't know how to scroll so I can change the position in the `largediv`. Another thing is that the start div has overflow hidden.
Here is the jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/zander_pope/xd4fb1nz/

Comment: Maybe you just want to alter #largediv's top and left when the cursor is X px away from the edge? I'm not sure how else you are going to "scroll" but just mousing the "ball" around

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `mousewheel` function.

```
$("#start").on("mousewheel", function(e){    
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
        scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
    $(this).scrollTop(scrollTop+(e.originalEvent.deltaY));
    $(this).scrollLeft(scrollLeft+(e.originalEvent.deltaX));
    return false;
})
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/xd4fb1nz/6/)

Comment: Almost what I want. I need it to move when the ball moves so it can be in the center of the map, or the div should scroll when the ball is at 50px from the margin.